# Beamer: Media 9 with overlay

Tags: beamer, media9

I've used `\includemedia` to insert an animation (.swf file) in my slides. It works. 
Besides the animation, I also want to include three bullet items that show up one after one, which are done by `\item<1->`, `\item<2->`, `\item<3->`. I want the animation to keep running during all three items.

The problem is, the animation needs to be either reloaded (if set `activate=pageopen`, which takes time to reload) or click (if set `activate=onclick`, which I prefer). Below is my MWE. Is there a better solution?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includemedia[width=5cm,height=2.5cm,activate=onclick,deactivate=pageclose]    
{\colorbox{white}{click}}{test.swf}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> \textbf{\texttt{One}}
\item<2-> \textbf{\texttt{Two}}
\item<3-> \textbf{\texttt{Three}}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test neither your code nor my suggestion (my viewers don't work with `media9`), but this might work: `\onslide<1-3>{\includemedia[width=5cm,height=2.5cm,activate=onclick,deactivate=pageclose]    
{\colorbox{white}{click}}{test.swf}}`

Comment: I just tried `\onslides` and the animation still looks like to reload after every item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Beamer overlays produce individual physical PDF pages for each visual state of the presentation frame. There is no way to 'pull' the loaded FlashPlayer plugin with the running SWF file therein from one page to the next. Instead, every page loads its own instance of FlashPlayer with the SWF running from start.